# How to quickly find all colors in an image

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I need to analyze an image to find all colors in a PNG or GIF image. I currently load the image to a canvas, then get the image data, then loop through every pixel and check it against each color in the palette. It takes forever, the browser thinks the script has stopped and it sometimes just crashes. Hoping there is a better way.

```
        //load file
        var fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = function(e) {
            var img = new Image();
            img.onload = function() {

                //create a new pixel with the images dimentions
                newPixel(this.width, this.height, []);

                //draw the image onto the canvas
                context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

                var colorPalette = [];
                var imagePixelData = context.getImageData(0,0,this.width, this.height).data;

                console.log(imagePixelData)
                for (var i = 0; i < imagePixelData.length; i += 4) {
                    var color = rgbToHex(imagePixelData[i],imagePixelData[i + 1],imagePixelData[i + 2]);
                    if (colorPalette.indexOf(color) == -1) {
                        colorPalette.push(color);

                        //don't allow more than 256 colors to be added
                        if (colorPalette.length >= settings.maxColorsOnImportedImage) {
                          alert('The image loaded seems to have more than '+settings.maxColorsOnImportedImage+' colors.')
                          break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                createColorPalette(colorPalette, false);

                //track google event
                ga('send', 'event', 'Pixel Editor Load', colorPalette.length, this.width+'/'+this.height); /*global ga*/

            };
            img.src = e.target.result;
        };
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
```

Comment: Use the color strings as object property names instead of putting them in an array so that instead of the linear search used by `.indexOf()` you use the optimized property name lookup mechanism instead. That'll probably make it tremendously faster.

Comment: ... though if you're really quitting after only 256 colors, it shouldn't be *that* bad.

Comment: `loop through every pixel`, correct me if I'm wrong. but it looks like your not checking every pixel(`i += 4`). And how big are the test images? It wouldn't surprise me when it crashes if the pictures are 5000x5000

Comment: The pixels are stored in array with rgba values separated so that's why we skip to every 4th one. It hangs for unacceptably long even on a 300x300px image.

Comment: Have you tried precalculating the `imagePixelData.length` value that you use in the loop test?

Comment: There's a lot we cant see here, such as `newPixel` and (probably more importantly) `rgbToHex`. In any case it should be easy enough to produce a [mcve] for people to play around with to find the source of your problem.

Comment: After some testing, precalculating `imagePixelData.length` and using that in the loop is a *lot* faster. It appears that the `length` property is calculated (in IE/Edge at least) each time it is called. See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/4v6877cr/).

Comment: If you're going to be using CPU intensive tasks, I'd recommend leveraging [WebWorkers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) so that you can at least eliminate the unresponsive warnings.

Comment: Here's my MCVE: http://jsfiddle.net/29sVC/1247/ precalculating the length didn't seem to make a difference (though I'm in FF), and using an object instead of an array reduced it a bit, but it's still far from ideal as you can tell. Takes about 30 seconds to load this image: http://pixeljoint.com/files/icons/full/partia.png

Comment: So um... I tried it without the RgbToHex function, instead just combining them into a string and comparing them that way... and now it finishes in less than a tenth of a second. http://jsfiddle.net/twL5xrck/1/

Answer (score 0):

This will speed things up a little.

The function indexof will search all of the array if it can not find an entry. This can be very slow, you can improve the speed of the search by adding to the top of the array moving down then searching for the index from the top most entry. This ensures that the search is only over added entries not the entire array.

Also use 32Bit words rather than 8bit bytes, use typed arrays as they are significantly quicker that pushing onto a array and don't convert to hex inside the loop it is redundant and can be done after on the smaller data set.

See comments for logic.

```
//draw the image onto the canvas
ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
// get size
const size = image.width * image.height;
// create pallete buffer
const colors32 = new Uint32Array(256);
// current pos of palette entry
var palettePos = colors32.length - 1;  // Start from top as this will speed up indexOf function 
// pixel data as 32 bit words so you can handle a pixel at a time rather than bytes.
const imgData = new Uint32Array(ctx.getImageData(0, 0, image.width,  image.height).data.buffer);;
// hold the color. If the images are low colour (less 256) it is highly probable that many pixels will
// be the same as the previous. You can avoid the index search if this is the case.
var color= colors32[palettePos --] = imgData[0]; // assign first pixels to ease logic in loop
for (var i = 1; i < size && palettePos >= 0; i += 1) { // loop till al pixels read if palette full
    if(color !== imgData[i]){ // is different than previouse
        if (colors32.indexOf(imgData[i], palettePos) === -1) { // is in the pallet
            color = colors32[palettePos --] = imgData[i]; // add it
        }
    }
}
// all the performance issues are over so now convert to the palette format you wanted.
const colorPalette = [];
colors32.reverse();
const paletteSize = (255 - palettePos) * 4;
const colors8 = new Uint8Array(colors32.buffer);
for(i = 0; i < paletteSize; i += 4){
    colorPalette.push(rgbToHex(colors8[i],colors8[i + 1],colors8[i + 2]));
}
```